# NewtonsoftJson JsonProperty is not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-7.0, minimal-apis

I'm using .NET 7 and Minimal API.
I would like to use NewtonsoftJson
and this is the class that I'm using:

```
public class FileNameRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("some_name")]
    public int SomeName { get; set; }
}
```

My Endpoint:

```
app.MapPost("/weatherforecast", (FileNameRequest file) =>
{
    var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
        new WeatherForecast
        (
            DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        ))
        .ToArray();
    return forecast;
})
.WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
.WithOpenApi();
```

In my program:

```
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            });
```

And it's not working.
How can i make [JsonProperty("some_name")] work with .NET 7 and minimal API?

Comment: Are you sure it's using Json.NET at all, rather than System.Text.Json? Where are you configuring that? (If you really don't care which implementation you use, then you probably just want to change `[JsonProperty]` to `[JsonPropertyName]`.)

Comment: i want to use the JsonProperty :) and not the JsonPropertyName of the system

Comment: Then you need to configure ASP.NET Core to use Json.NET. Have you done that, or tried to do it? You can't just use the Json.NET attributes and assume the system will reconfigure itself to use Json.NET by default.

Comment: @VadimTomashevsky if you really-really want to - check the duplicate. But I would recommend to stick with the `System.Text.Json`.

Answer (score 0):

your symptom should be the expected behavior because we have [document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configure-json-deserialization-options-for-body-binding), so we have to use `[JsonPropertyName("some_name")]` like Jon said in the comment.

> The body binding source uses System.Text.Json for deserialization. It
> is **not possible** to change this default, but JSON serialization and
> deserialization options can be configured.

After using `JsonPropertyName` it worked.

[image]

Comment: JsonPropertyName - i know that it;s working with it, but what attribute are using for the class it self? a lot of people used to work with the NewtonsoftJson so this is why i have asked for it

Comment: `used to work with the NewtonsoftJson` could you pls find a sample for that? Mini API starts to in use from .NET 7 and the document already mentioned it's impossible to use `NewtonsoftJson` for parameter binding.

Comment: @TinyWang Minimal APIs are present since .NET 6. Also in theory you can jump through some hoops and use Newtonsoft's Json.NET with Minimal APIs. See the duplicate.